Tibco rendezvous Docker multicast
I have an application built on the .NET Framework that uses Tibco Rendezvous. I am currently investigating the availability of a Docker image for Tibco Rendezvous that supports multicast communication.
I conducted some initial research, but I have not yet found a suitable image.

Multicast communications are not supported in Cloud environments, but using Rendezvous router daemons it is possible to route Rendezvous messages between hosts using a TCP point to point transport.
You can have a look to the TIBCO Rendezvous Network Service solution, that is basically the Rendezvous Router packaged for Kubernetes, the official product documentation is available here:
https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-rendezvous-network-service-2-1-0
